Как мне изменить фото без текста по кнопке снизу в телеграм боте на aiogram?
if first:
    bot_message = await query.message.answer_photo(photo=FSInputFile(file_paths[index]), reply_markup=markup)
    await state.update_data(bot_message=bot_message)
else:
    state_data = await state.get_data()
    bot_message: Message = state_data["bot_message"]
    await bot_message.message.edit_media(InputMediaPhoto(media=FSInputFile(file_paths[index])), reply_markup=markup)

Как мне здесь изменить фото без его удаления?
